# REGEX matches in tester but not C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a line from a file: `; STRING WBSALT1()`

and code

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s*(;)(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
   {
       //do
       //stuff
   }
```

For some reason the REGEX isn't matching that line in the file. I ran it through a tester and it catches it just fine. Does anyone know what else could be causing the problem?

it will, however, match this (in code, not in a regex tester)

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s*(string)\s*(.*\()\s*(\d*)\)\s*;?(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

which really doesn't make any sense to me. I have no other issues with the thousands of other lines in the file that look similar. Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**: Okay so I didn't place it in the question because I didn't think it necessary. Apparently it is:

My ACTUAL `if` statement looks like this:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s*;.*") || !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s*(origin)\s*(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

Now, when I take off the `||` statement it works properly. Why it is doing this I do not understand. Maybe someone has some insight into this?

Comment: Sorry for what might seem like a stupid question, but you have a `!` in your `if`, is that intentional?

Comment: C# Regex **does** match it.

Comment: @Vache Yes that is intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add you don't need `IgnoreCase` set here if you're using `.*` and you can lose the capture groups. You may also want to add beginning `^` and ending `$` line anchors.

Tested on [`Ideone`](http://ideone.com/xArxVg)

```
string line = "; STRING WBSALT1()";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\s*;.*$")) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want the AND operator instead? `if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\s*;.*$") && !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s*(origin)\s*(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) { ...`

Comment: I just tried the `&&` instead of `||` and it worked! Why is that?! Edit your answer and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: With the OR (`||`) operator, if the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to true or false.

Comment: I wasn't thinking it through properly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also combine your expressions into one instead of using multiple statements. `if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\s*(?:origin|;)\s*.*$"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) { ..`

Answer (score 4):

Tested in my environment and works as expected.

```
        string line = "; STRING WBSALT1()";

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s*(;)(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
           {
               //do
               //stuff
           }
```

Wondering if maybe you did not intend for the "!" to be part of the condition

```
 if(! ...
```

Regards,

Comment: I am intending to use `!`. I suppose there's something else going on. When I go into my Immediate Window and paste `Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\s*(;)(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` when line is set to `; STRING WBSALT1()` I get a true response back. Something else is happening that I cannot see.